# How to make facebook crawl correct url on multi market, multi language site?

Tags: facebook, geoip, canonical-link

We have a website with multiple markets and multiple language where we use canonical to avoid duplicate content.

A geoip matching script is used to redirect users to what we guess is their market by looking at their ip.

The problems occurs when we try to add a link on facebook to the site. Facebook crawls the canonical instead of the page url and links to wrong market due to geoip redirect.

Example:
Url /nl-nl/nl/locator
canonical /nl-nl/global/locator

en = language 
fi = market/country

When a new user comes to /nl-nl/global/locator, we look at the ip and try to redirect the user to the market that the ip corresponds if the market has the language connected.

So far so good.

The problem is that since the facebook crawler is seen as a new visitor coming to  /nl-nl/global/locator with a different ip than the person trying to create the link they wont get the same market and link unless the language is only used in one market and the user isn't in the same country. The content is the same but the market is wrong. instead of /nl-nl/nl/locator the facebook post links to en /nl-nl/be/locator

Essentially I would like facebook to ignore the canonical and use the specified url but I'm not sure if it possible or the correct path to solve this.